# Decrypting Files Copied from Dell Encrypted Thumb Drive

Tags: encryption, usb-flash-drive, xml, decryption

I am attempting to decrypt files I copied from my thumbdrive, which my Dell laptop encrypted.

First, I encrypted the thumb drive with my Dell laptop and then I added image files to it.  That part went fine.

My image printer service requires non-encrypted thumb drives, so I took the encrypted thumb drive to a non-encrypted computer, and copied those files from my encrypted thumb drive to the hard drive, and from there to a non-encrypted thumb drive.

(My mistake was to not copy the files from the "EMS explorer" (software view on the encrypted thumbdrive which contains the decrypted files) but instead the Windows explorer view of the encrypted thumbdrive (which shows the encrypted files), and thus I copied encrypted, rather than non-encrypted files, to the non-encrypted computer.)

I repeated this process, deleting the previous files on the thumb drive by copying the subsequent files over them, before I realized my mistake.  In other words, the original encrypted files no longer exist on my encrypted thumb drive.

I was wondering if there is a way to decrypt the files I copied to the computer?  I looked at the files on the encrypted thumb drive, and I noticed the VolumeInfo.xml file, which shows a shield date created several months ago.  Also, there is a ShieldID in the xml file. The VolumeInfo.xml file was never deleted.

Can these fields be used to decrypt, and is there a tool which would allow me to use the ShieldId or other fields from the xml file, to decrypt those files?

Thanks for any leads.

Comment: "I was wondering if there is a way to decrypt the files I copied to the computer?" - Which computer are we talking about exactly?

Comment: It's just a second computer, non-encrypted.  The first computer encrypted that first thumb drive.

Comment: If the computer you are asking about is not encrypted.  What exactly is the question?

Comment: Geez.... if you re-read the question, you'll see that I am trying to get the files from an encrypted drive, onto an unencrypted drive.  I did that, but I mistakenly copied them from the explorer view (as opposed to the Dell decrypted view).  Thus, the files are still encrypted.  The second computer is really irrelevant in this, as the original encryption files are still on the encrypted thumb drive.